# Duplicated logs when using Serilog.Sink.Elasticsearch 8 with buffer

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, logging, kibana, serilog

I am using **.NET 4.6.2** Application with **Serilog** with **Elasticsearch sink 8** to send logs to our Elasticsearch cluster. We also added the buffer settings to avoid losing any data.

Everything was working fine with Elasticsearch Sink 7.x until we upgrade to the latest version to make it compatible with with Elasticsearch 7 (cluster).

With the newer version, logs are duplicated (triplicated or more) and sometimes they are not even saved in Elasticsearch.

I believe must be something wrong with my buffer settings.

This is my test code:

```
private static ILogger GetLogger()
{
    string indexName = "buffertest";

    var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .WriteTo.Console();

    var esSink = new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("https://myelasticdomain.com:9200"))
    {
        AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
        AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv7,
        TemplateName = indexName,
        IndexFormat = indexName + "-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}",
        ModifyConnectionSettings = c => c.BasicAuthentication("myuser", "****"),
        CustomFormatter = new ExceptionAsObjectJsonFormatter(renderMessage: true)
    };

    // buffer
    esSink.BufferBaseFilename = $@"C:\logs\ElasticSeriLog\buffer-{indexName}";
    esSink.SingleEventSizePostingLimit = null;
    esSink.BufferFileSizeLimitBytes = 1000 * 1000 * 100; // 100 MB
    esSink.BufferFileCountLimit = 50;

    loggerConfig.WriteTo.Elasticsearch(esSink);

    return loggerConfig.CreateLogger();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = GetLogger();

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        var lineNumer = i + 1;
        var msgToLog = GetTextToLog();
        Log.Information("{Line}{Message}", lineNumer, msgToLog);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();

    Console.WriteLine("Flushing...");
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I found what the issue is. Serilog.Sink.Elasticsearch version 8.0.0 contains a bug  (#266) which prevents the buffer files from being processed. This has been fixed in the current DEV branch but not released yet.